# Bouba/Kiki effect - computer-generated 3D shapes

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, reference-request

I have seen a research project, where the subjects were presented with shapes to classify in two categories. The shapes were 3D models, some that were "pointy" and some that were "rounded".

The categories were labelled with two artificial words, one that subjects intuitively would classify as a "pointy" word, and the other a "rounded" word (only based on the configuration of consonants and vowels in the artificial word).

The effect is called the **bouba/kiki effect**. The article I seek used computer generated 3D models

Could you give a reference to this project? (Home page or citation).

Comment: I found a related article (2D shapes instead of 3D) : 

"Implicit sound symbolism in lexical access: Evidence from an interference task. Chris Westbury, Brain and Language Volume 93, Issue 1, April 2005, Pages 10-19"

Comment: I think the question is clear, but it seems like you have what you need to answer it yourself: have you simply searched Google Scholar for "bouba kiki 3D"? Perhaps not every result will match what you are looking for or necessarily be the exact paper you recall, but we won't know which one you've seen either.

Comment: Well, I did get a lttle closer (I found the name of the effect). And you're right, you couldn't possible know what article I have seen - I just assumed that it was well-known, while in fact there are several similar articles.

Comment: Although the question is appropriate as is, note that your edit incorporating the 'bouba/kiki' effect could potentially also have been posted as an answer. You are in the best position to judge whether the general effect name answers your question, or you are still looking for a more specific article. In case you are looking for a more specific article, it would make sense to elaborate why.

Comment: Alternatively, in case the name of the effect answers your question, feel free to edit it out of the question and post it as an answer yourself.